# Jenkind delete builds log and slaves build log

Tags: jenkins

I'm using curl to delete Jenkins build logs as is:

```
curl -kg -X POST -u $USER:$PASSWD $JENKINS_URL/job/$JOB_NAME/$build_number/doDelete
```

And it works. But this jobs has two slaves wth its build logs, and these logs remains on the system. How I can delete build log and build slaves log? Thanks.

Comment: Are you talikng about the job workspaces on the slaves/nodes? I don't see build logs on my nodes. There are lots of options to delete workspaces (eg: plugin, or grooy - doDoWipeOutWorkspace() )

Comment: No, I'm just talking about build logs from the GUI.

Comment: Then I think you have your answer. There only job build logs are on the master.

Comment: For example, build number 90 I see from the GUI is deleted from the master, but if I navigate into slaves GUI I still see build number 90 and slave log, so are not deleted. curl command above delete only master build logs, but I want to delete every logs relative to a particular build

Comment: I can't help you then. If  if doDelete on http://jenkins:8080/job/MyJob/47/
I no longer see it under : http://jenkins:8080/NodeA/builds